# Conditional ROW_NUMBER() to skip nulls still counting them

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to add a ROW_NUMBER column to a data set that follows the order of [Withdrawal then Fee; Withdrawal then Fee] based upon whether the column `NETWORKCD` is null. However, my row_number formula is still counting Nulls even though it's not displaying the numbers, like so:

```
+--------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| Acctid | Transaction |  PostDate  | NetworkCd | PeriodCount |
+--------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|  12345 | Withdrawal  | 10/4/2018  | FRGN      |           1 |
|  12345 | Fee         | 10/4/2018  |           |             |
|  12345 | Withdrawal  | 10/11/2018 | FRGN      |           3 |
|  12345 | Fee         | 10/11/2018 |           |             |
|  12345 | Withdrawal  | 10/22/2018 | FRGN      |           5 |
|  12345 | Fee         | 10/22/2018 |           |             |
+--------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

I am using the following formula for `PeriodCount`

```
(case when networkcd is not null 
      then row_number() over (partition by acctid order by postdate) 
 end) PeriodCount
```

I was expecting PeriodCount to count [1,2,3] instead of [1,3,5], like so:

```
+--------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| Acctid | Transaction |  PostDate  | NetworkCd | PeriodCount |
+--------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|  12345 | Withdrawal  | 10/4/2018  | FRGN      |           1 |
|  12345 | Fee         | 10/4/2018  |           |             |
|  12345 | Withdrawal  | 10/11/2018 | FRGN      |           2 |
|  12345 | Fee         | 10/11/2018 |           |             |
|  12345 | Withdrawal  | 10/22/2018 | FRGN      |           3 |
|  12345 | Fee         | 10/22/2018 |           |             |
+--------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The row_number() is exactly that in this instance, the row number, whether you choose to display it or replace it with a null in the case statement, does not alter which row number it is.

Comment: @Andrew That was my first thought, but doesn't the case statement for networkcd is not null adjust for that?

Comment: Afraid not, Dense_Rank as Alex has posted is the way forward, subtle difference in how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still showing a value the 1st, 3rd and 5th rows - so the row count as it encounters each of those rows is correct. It's the row number within the entire result set, not within the not-null values. Your case expression is deciding whether to show the value, not affecting how it is found.

You could get the result you want using `dense_rank()` instead;

```
with your_table (Acctid, Transaction, PostDate, NetworkCd) as (
          select 12345, 'Withdrawal', to_date('10/4/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'FRGN' from dual
union all select 12345, 'Fee', to_date('10/4/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null from dual
union all select 12345, 'Withdrawal', to_date('10/11/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'FRGN' from dual
union all select 12345, 'Fee', to_date('10/11/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null from dual
union all select 12345, 'Withdrawal', to_date('10/22/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'FRGN' from dual
union all select 12345, 'Fee', to_date('10/22/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null from dual
)
select Acctid, Transaction, PostDate, NetworkCd,
(case when networkcd is not null then dense_rank() over (partition by acctid order by postdate) end) as periodcount
from your_table;

    ACCTID TRANSACTIO POSTDATE   NETW PERIODCOUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---- -----------
     12345 Withdrawal 2018-10-04 FRGN           1
     12345 Fee        2018-10-04                 
     12345 Withdrawal 2018-10-11 FRGN           2
     12345 Fee        2018-10-11                 
     12345 Withdrawal 2018-10-22 FRGN           3
     12345 Fee        2018-10-22
```

... as that does suppress gaps in the generated values. [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/DENSE_RANK.html):

> `DENSE_RANK` computes the rank of a row in an ordered group of rows and returns the rank as a `NUMBER`. The ranks are consecutive integers beginning with 1. ...

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I'll spend some time looking into Dense_rank().

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `partition by acctid` to `partition by acctid, NetworkCd IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2):

Alex Poole's answer works, but relies on the fact that your null rows have the same `POSTDATE` as the non-null rows you want to count. If you change the dates to be different from one another, you see that the dense_rank fails:

```
with your_table (Acctid, Transaction, PostDate, NetworkCd) as (
              select 12345, 'Withdrawal', to_date('10/1/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'FRGN'
    union all select 12345, 'Fee', to_date('10/2/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null
    union all select 12345, 'Withdrawal', to_date('10/3/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'FRGN'
    union all select 12345, 'Fee', to_date('10/4/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null
    union all select 12345, 'Withdrawal', to_date('10/5/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'FRGN'
    union all select 12345, 'Fee', to_date('10/6/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null
    )

select
    Acctid,
    Transaction,
    PostDate,
    NetworkCd,
    case when networkcd is not null then dense_rank() over (partition by Acctid order by PostDate) end as PeriodCount,
    dense_rank() over (partition by Acctid order by PostDate) as DenseRank
from your_table
order by Acctid, PostDate, Transaction
;
```

yields

```
acctid  transaction  postdate    networkcd  periodcount  denserank
------  -----------  ----------  ---------  -----------  ---------
12345   Withdrawal   2018-10-01  FRGN       1            1
12345   Fee          2018-10-02                          2
12345   Withdrawal   2018-10-03  FRGN       3            3
12345   Fee          2018-10-04                          4
12345   Withdrawal   2018-10-05  FRGN       5            5
12345   Fee          2018-10-06                          6
```

(on the right, showing the results of dense_rank without the null conditional) so it works in your case but isn't reliable overall.

Kevin Siemons's answer works better: it counts null and non-null rows separately, and you can simply hide the count you're doing on the null rows:

```
with your_table (Acctid, Transaction, PostDate, NetworkCd) as (
              select 12345, 'Withdrawal', to_date('10/1/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'FRGN'
    union all select 12345, 'Fee', to_date('10/2/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null
    union all select 12345, 'Withdrawal', to_date('10/3/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'FRGN'
    union all select 12345, 'Fee', to_date('10/4/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null
    union all select 12345, 'Withdrawal', to_date('10/5/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'FRGN'
    union all select 12345, 'Fee', to_date('10/6/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), null
    )

select
    Acctid,
    Transaction,
    PostDate,
    NetworkCd,
    case when networkcd is not null then row_number() over (partition by Acctid, NetworkCd is not null order by PostDate) end as PeriodCount,
    row_number() over (partition by Acctid, NetworkCd is not null order by PostDate) as RowNumber
from your_table
order by Acctid, PostDate, Transaction
;
```

yields

```
acctid  transaction  postdate    networkcd  periodcount  rownumber
------  -----------  ----------  ---------  -----------  ---------
12345   Withdrawal   2018-10-01  FRGN       1            1
12345   Fee          2018-10-02                          1
12345   Withdrawal   2018-10-03  FRGN       2            2
12345   Fee          2018-10-04                          2
12345   Withdrawal   2018-10-05  FRGN       3            3
12345   Fee          2018-10-06                          3
```

I recommend that—using `case when networkcd is not null then row_number() over (partition by Acctid, NetworkCd is not null order by PostDate) end as PeriodCount`.

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER()` function doesn't work as you expected, but you can do instead :

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table t1
        where t1.acctid = t.acctid and t1.PostDate <= t.PostDate and
              t1.networkcd is not null 
       ) as PeriodCount
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like instead of being NULL it is an empty string. SQL will regard that differently in the code.

Try:

```
case when networkcd = '' then row_number()....
```

Comment: [Oracle Database treats a character value with a length of zero as null.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Nulls.html). The result of comparing anything with `= ''` is the same as `= null`, which is 'unknown'.